# Ubuntu Tweak compatible with 14.04?

Tags: updates

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and cannot update due to full root despite running autoremove and autoclean.  I installed Ubuntu Tweak but clicking on the icon does nothing.

Comment: You are going to need to either make the partition bigger or uninstall a bunch of stuff and remove old downloads as a full root can cause a ton of other problems as well